# Google Analytics campaign tracking via the utm_campaign query parameter

Tags: google-analytics

I've placed URLs in my newsletter like this: www.mydomain.com/?utm_campaign=summer

Now in Google Analytics I want to see when and how many visitors came to my site via this 'summer' campaign.

I tried looking under `Traffic Sources > Campaigns`, but I don't see anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing utm_source and utm_medium which are required parameters. You can use Google Analytics URL builder to help you build correct links: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55578